# can anybody explain what are these errors in python code. It is a malware analysis code in python using keras package

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, compiler-errors, malware

so this is the code that i am trying to run

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from copy import deepcopy
import gc

from col_headers import Header
from experiments import Experiments, Configs
from experiments.useful import timestamped_to_vector, unison_shuffled_copies, extract_neg

# Load data
headers = Header()
c = headers.classification_col
v = headers.vector_col
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

test = data[data["test_set"] == True]
train = data[data["test_set"] == False]

train = train.as_matrix(columns=headers.training_headers)
test = test.as_matrix(columns=headers.training_headers)

x_test, y_test = timestamped_to_vector(test, vector_col=v, time_start=0, classification_col=c)
x_train, y_train = timestamped_to_vector(train, vector_col=v, time_start=0, classification_col=c)

# Random search with thresholding 
rand_params = Configs.get_all()

expt = Experiments.Experiment(rand_params, search_algorithm="random",
                              data=(x_train, y_train), folds=10, folder_name="random_search_reults",
                              thresholding=True, threshold=0.5)

# parameter configurations
A_B_C = Configs.get_A_B_C

# Ensemble model 
ensemble_config = Experiments.Ensemble_configurations(list(A_B_C.values()),
                                                      x_test=x_test, y_test=y_test,
                                                      x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train,
                                                      folder_name="test_train_results",`your text`
                                                      batch_size=64)
ensemble_config.run_experiments()
```

These are the error messages i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\awais ramzan\Documents\papaer\malware-prediction-rnn-master\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: It means you havent installed `pandas` package. Use `pip3 install pandas` if you are using pip as package manager. For other installations, see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html